# How to insert more than one row of data into a table at one time

Tags: table

I would like to populate a custom table, with more than one row of data at one time. If I delete the second array, it will insert one row of data. It won't add both rows at the same time though. How do I insert both rows at the same time? My code:

```
function mp_install_name_data() {
    global $wpdb;
    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "names";

    $wpdb->insert(
        $table_name,
        array(
            'id' => '1',
            'name' => 'matt',
            'age' => '20',
            'point_one' => '0.45',
            'point_two' => '0.22'     
        ),

         array(
            'id' => '2',
            'name' =>'james',
            'age' => '6',
            'point_one' => '0.27',
            'point_two' => '0.17'  
        )
    );  

         }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a foreach loop -

```
function mp_install_name_data() {
    global $wpdb;
    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "names";

    $rows = array(
        array(
            'id' => '1',
            'name' => 'matt',
            'age' => '20',
            'point_one' => '0.45',
            'point_two' => '0.22'     
        ),
        array(
            'id' => '2',
            'name' =>'james',
            'age' => '6',
            'point_one' => '0.27',
            'point_two' => '0.17'  
        )
    );

    foreach( $rows as $row )
    {
        $wpdb->insert( $table_name, $row);  
    }
}
```

Comment: I was also using `DECIMAL` in the sql query, & changed it to `float` . Would this have made a difference for `point_one` & `point_two` ? Thank-you.

Comment: Sorry, i am not sure what your are trying to say. But if you mean your `point_one` & `point_two` value is different than what you have used for the insert statement, then the problem could be from the field type set for those two fields.

Comment: @shazzard. Sorry, let me clarify. In the sql statement that creates the custom table. For the `point_one` & `point_two` columns, should I use `DECIMAL` or `FLOAT` in the sql statement? Does it matter which one I use? Thank-you

Comment: check this reference http://stackoverflow.com/q/5150274/712612

Answer (score 1):

You can't insert more than one row using one call to `$wpdb->insert`, however you can use `$wpdb` to perform a raw sql query with `$wpdb->query`.

For MySQL syntax [see docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert.html).

Remember to use `$wpdb->prepare` to escape data before inserting.

```
$wpdb->query( $wpdb->prepare(
  "INSERT INTO $table_name (id, name, age, point_one, point_two)
  VALUES (%d, %s, %d, %s, %s), (%d, %s, %d, %s, %s);"
), 1, 'matt', 20, '0.45', '0.22', 2, 'james', 6, '0.27', '0.17', );
```

Tip: if you setup the id column to be `AUTOINCREMENT` you don't need to pass the id, it will be added automatically

Comment: Thank-you. It is possible to use  `$wpdb->insert` , see below if you like

Comment: @mattnewbie I say that you can't using **one** call, the  answer you accept call `$wpdb->insert` **two** times with a foreach loop. But in that way you make 2 database queries, using my method you run only one query. If you do this task a lot of times or for a lot of rows, performance improvement can be **very** high.

Comment: Thanks, after re-reading it, I understand the difference!

Answer (score 0):

If you are concerned by performance, you should consider adding the START TRANSACTION and COMMIT instructions:

```
mysql_query('START TRANSACTION');
$res1 = mysql_query('query1');
$res2 = mysql_query('query2');
If ( $res1 && $res2 )
    mysql_query('COMMIT');
```